# take the first non null/empty cell of all column from a DataFrame

Tags: python

I have a dataframe df that contains hundreds of columns. What i want is keep only the first non empty cell.

df:

| Datetime index | trade 1 | trade 2 | ...... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 |  |  | ...... |
| 2/1/2021 | 1.15 |  | ...... |
| 3/1/2021 | 1.21 | 1.31 | ...... |
| 4/1/2021 | 1.23 | 1.16 | ...... |

Expected df:

| index | trade 1 | trade 2 | ...... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.15 | 1.31 | ...... |

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a function called `first_valid_index()`, which returns the index value for the first non-NA/null row.

So you can do something like

```
trade1 = df['trade 1'].first_valid_index()
trade2 = df['trade 2'].first_valid_index()
#...
d = {'trade 1':[df.at[trade1,'trade 1']],'trade 2':[df.at[trade2,'trade 2']]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

However, since you said you have hundreds of columns, you probably want to iterate over all of those columns rather than type them all in individually. You can loop over it all with something like this

```
colSize = len(df.columns)
d = {} #make a blank dictionary to later put all of our data in
for n in range(1,colSize):
    first = df.iloc[:,n].first_valid_index() #gets that first non-null row in that column
    colName = list(df)[n] #gets the column name
    d.update({colName:[df.at[first,colName]]}) #updates our temporary dictionary to hold our column name and the value from that non-null row
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: it got stuck on the line code:  d.update({colName:[df.at[first,colName]]})

Comment: Did you include the line `d = {}` above it? we need to create the blank dictionary before we can later update it. Can you post whatever sort of error message you got?

Comment: it shows up ---->      d.update({colName:[final_df.at[first,colName]]}) KeyError: None

Comment: Also the first variable gives the index  and not the price.

Comment: I see in the code where you got the error that you are using `final_df` instead of `df`; are you correctly using the `final_df` everywhere else?
Another potential issue could be with the colName variable - is it spelled the same everywhere with the same cases?
And for first - correct, it gives you the index, not the value in that cell itself. When you do the `d.update()` line, the `df.at([first,colName])` finds the value in that cell by looking at index `first` and column `colName`.